# Is there a way to tell if a table/row is involved in a different session's transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, innodb

Is there a way to tell whether a table or a table row is being used in a transaction at the current moment by another session?

Comment: Yes it is. I ask about an SQL query may return any output about the current transactional state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually view outstanding row locks in transactions with SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS if you enable the [lock monitor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-monitors.html), but you'll need to parse the results to get anything usable. These locks are usually only momentary. They disappear after the transaction is committed.

If you're trying to serialize your queries, you can implement table locking (for a whole table), or (with InnoDB) row level locking using SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE (or you can let MySQL do this for you with the [SERIALIZABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html) isolation mode).

You can even come up with your own locking scheme using values stored in the database, which I've seen many implement.

The default [innodb_lock_wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html) is 50 seconds and applies to all row level locks in InnoDB. There is no lock wait timeout for table locks.

If you're more specific, such as providing an actual scenario and the desired behavior, we'll be able to answer in more detail.

Comment: Could I able to dynamically set innodb_lock_wait_timeout through an sql query?

Comment: @SaidBakr, No, unfortunately [innodb_lock_wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout) is not a dynamic variable. You must set it at startup.

Answer (score 1):

Being able to detect changes *before* they're committed would rather damage the whole concept of ACID.

Generally, if a table or row is currently involved in a transaction, it will be locked and you will not be able to change it. If you try to *view* it, you'll see it as it was before any uncommitted changes. This is a good reason to keep even transactions short-lived (don't lock rows while waiting for user input for example).

For updating, what you'll eventually see, if the transaction takes too long, is a timeout (assuming it's configured).

That's the whole point of ACID - you either see all the changes or none of them - there is no point where you can see a partial change, and rarely is there a use case for knowing in advance.

---

What I would suggest is rethinking your question. Asking how to fix something in a specific way is counter-productive to you. You should state the actual problem and ask how to fix it. That way, we'll understand the background better and you won't limit yourself to a small subset of possible solutions.

Comment: Well! I do not want to see anything if there a transaction process is occured on the table by another session. How could I handle this?

You talked about "For updating, what you'll eventually see is a timeout (if configured)." How could I see the timeout or configure it?

Comment: @Said, it's usually built into the DBMS, not sure how to configure it under MySQL. But, take heed of my final paragraph. You seem to be trying to bypass one of the best features of database technology. If you don't want to see changes from a separate uncommitted transaction, you won't, not until the other session commits. Take one step back and tell us the _actual_ problem you're having. Pre-supposing a solution is rarely a good idea in trouble-shooting.

Comment: Well,
I will describe the logic flow. There is a table handles a list of tasks for users. Each task has a modified property which represents the datetime at which this task is did last time.

I perform a select to bring out tasks that modified before the last 24 hours, then there are a loop turns around the result and for every task there is some logic done and finally update the datetime of each task to the current datetime.
The execution of this query and tasks is embedded in every application page.The problem when two users visits the website at the same time, the logic of the task repeated